# Full Calendar Week View

Tags: fullcalendar

I use fullcalendar v2.7.3. I want to show the left time grid on the top and the day grid at left which show on the top Please refer the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: As per https://fullcalendar.io/docs/views/Available_Views/ there are no built-in views which support what you're looking for, and no options which would cause it to happen. It would be a massive re-write of all the CSS and Javascript logic for positioning the grid, and events etc. Unfortunately I think your only option is to create a custom view from scratch: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/views/Custom_Views/ . This is a very large task. Ask yourself if it is really so essential to flip the grid or whether you can live with it - it works well now, and is more like a conventional paper calendar.